# Vuetify installation asking for permissions for a System's folder

Tags: vue.js, permissions, vuetify.js

I'm trying to install Vuetify on Windows but I was getting permission errors, so I ran a new terminal as an Admin. With this new terminal I got a new permission error after selecting the "Default" preset:

```
 ERROR  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup'
```

This folder is only allowed to the System, so I do not have any permission by default.

Is It really necessary to change the permissions on this folder for Vuetiy? It seemes to me a bit weird.

EDIT:
Here a screenshot of the error:
[image]

If I ran this not being an administrator I get the error:

```
 ERROR  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\$USER\Local settings'
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this error?

Comment: You shouldn't run npm as root in the first place, the real problem here is the original permission error you were trying to work around.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question adding the screenshot and the error I get when running the command as a normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running npm in the system folder. system folder is reserved for windows purposes only and is not for anything else. You might have noticed that when you install a new application like msoffice or kerbal space program or anything else, all those doesn't go to system32. it goes to a different folder in c drive named program files. If you mess up system32 then the computer will not start.

What you should do is, switch to any other drive like d drive in your system and then create a folder, give it a name, say 'myprojects', and then run the npm command over there. If you don't have any other drive in the system then create a new folder in the desktop name it as myprojects and then run npm commands.

Seems like you are just into the process of getting started with vue, what you are facing are just initial hurdles, keep learning. :)

How to install vue: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks! following this I finally made it